# Having a class instance as an optional input field for a function

Tags: python, class

Is there a cleaner way than using if/else statements to add an class instance as an optional field inside a function? Below is an example of using if/else statements to create an optional field for class instances:

```
  class hi:
    def __init__(self):
      self.ii = "foo"
      self.kk = "bar"



  def foo(myClass = None,**kwargs):
      if myClass.ii:
          print(myClass.ii)
      else:
          print("Nothing")

p=hi()
foo(p) #returns "foo"
foo() #returns "Nothing"
```

This can get difficult to read if there are lots of optional instances in the function. Is there a clean way to rewrite the if/else part of the function to be cleaner similar to the `kwargs.get` part in the example below:

```
  def foo(**kwargs):
       print (kwargs.get("aa", "Nothing"))

  foo(aa = "pii") #output: "pii"
  foo()#output: "Nothing"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(myClass, 'ii', 'Nothing')
```

This will also prevent your code from raising an `AttributeError` when the attribute doesn't exist, which is what would otherwise happen with your original code.

Comment: yep that is it. Just difficult to look for stuff when you don't know how to describe it without examples.